# How can I pull a Docker image from a private Docker Hub repo remotely?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have several images in Docker Hub private repositories, and I need to pull these on remote machines using the Docker remote Rest API. Is there a way of authenticating remotely?

These are the calls I'd like to make remotely:

```
docker login
docker pull myrepo/myimage
```

Answer (score 73):

Yes there is a way, you only need to specify the remote host

```
docker login myrepo.com
```

Then you can access to your images

```
docker pull myrepo.com/myimage
```

and you can specify a tag as well

```
docker pull myrepo.com/myimage:mytag
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do this using the remote api, which I don't think is possible

Comment: Then you can do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814714/docker-remote-api-pull-from-docker-hub-private-registry)

Comment: If you want you can login with password typing:                                                                        
docker login --username <myUsername> --password <myPassword>

Comment: FYI, `docker login` will write your username/password in base64 plaintext to `~/.docker/config.json`. So you may want to do `docker logout` afterwards to clear it.

Comment: @wisbucky Not true (checked in OSX) 

```cat ~/.docker/config.json


{
 "auths": {
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
 },
 "HttpHeaders": {
  "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.2 (darwin)"
 },
 "credsStore": "osxkeychain",
 "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
```

Comment: @HereHere Looks like `Docker for Mac` automatically sets up the docker credential helper. But [by default (e.g. Linux), docker will write the credentials in base64 plaintext](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login) to `~/.docker/config.json` unless you configure a credential helper. So you should not assume until you verify for your machine.

Comment: `sudo docker pull PRIVATE_REPO_NAME/DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:TAG` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I could fix the same issue only when I made the repo public. Make sure the repository is public then this is the set of instructions I followed in command line:
Once logout from docker hub and login again.

1- `docker logout`

2- `docker login --username=YOURUSERNAME`
Enter password when asked

3- `docker pull "repositoryName"/"imageName"[:tag]`

if "tag" is not included the default value will be "latest".
Then check the images by `docker images` command to check if its been pulled.

Answer (score -4):

docker image pull 127.0.0.1:5000 /jenkins:latest

The above ip is your private machine's ip and 5000 is your mapping port /jenkins:latest is your image name which is present in your private registry,
you can check it @ localhost:5000/v2/_catalog