# Is there a way to obtain the date when the docker image was created using docker API for python

Tags: python, docker, docker-api, python-docker

I would like to obtain the `created at` date for a docker image using docker API. Is this possible?
I don't see it in the docs https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html.
I see a way to obtain it using `requests` but was hoping to use `docker` API as my code uses docker API to grab other information such as Registry ID.

```
import docker
cli=docker.from_env()
cl_image = cli.images.get_registry_data(reg_url, auth_config=None)
image_hash = cl_image.id
```

Comment: Yes it does. I'm unsure how to use it though.

Answer (score 3):

The image creation timestamp is on the Image object, under the `attrs` property:

```
from dateutil.parser import isoparse
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

images = client.images.list()
img = images[0]

created_str = img.attrs["Created"]
created_datetime = isoparse(created_str)
print(created_datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, getting the creation date is not supported by the `Docker` SDK for python. The `create` attribute simply doesn't exist so you will not be able to get that value. So you will have to use the `request` module to fetch the data from `Docker API`.

Note: Your import library should not be referred to as `API` it is simply a library supporting the Docker Engine `API`. The real `API` is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ImageInspect) which you'll use it to make a `GET` request.

**Edit:**

I am not sure if you are doing your authentication correctly. You need to provide credentials with values and encode in base64url (JSON) and pass them as `X_Registry-Auth` header in your request call, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#section/Authentication). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824171/6505847)  perfectly illustrates what you have to do, albeit it's shown in the context of `cURL POST` request.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure how to implement it, trying it out. If you could share a snippet with any public docker image, that would be helpful.

Comment: @py_noob I have updated the URL, which points to the right steps you need to take. Configure your call with the required parameters and it should give you the response shown in the docs

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated. I however get a <Response [404]> for every url I provide so trying to debug that. Here's the code snippet: `rfinal=requests.get('https://gitlab-registry.nameofprogram.com/abc/source_repo/', headers={"PRIVATE_TOKEN": <enter_token_here>})`

Comment: For anyone finding this in the future, the python docker library supports this (and possibly in 2020 also?), under the `attrs` of an image object.